# How to insert a pair using multiset in C++

Tags: c++, std-pair, multiset

I want to insert an integer value and a pair in a multiset.

So I declared it as:

```
multiset < int, pair < int, int> > mp;
int m,n,p;
```

To insert in multiset I tried this :

```
mp.insert(make_pair(m, make_pair(n,p))); // Compile time error
```

But its giving compile time error... Could someone please suggest the correct method to implement it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a [`multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)?

Comment: @ildjarn yes i am sure because the keys can be duplicate...

Comment: They can in `multimap` too – hence the separate types `map` and `multimap`. ;-]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type `multiset<int,pair<int,int>>` is trying to create a multiset where the Key is `int` and the Compare is `pair<int,int>`. This is nonsensical. You either want to use

```
multiset<pair<int,pair<int,int>>>
```

or you want to use

```
multiset<tuple<int,int,int>>
```

The former type (`pair<int,pair<int,int>>`) matches the expression you're using to insert into the set (`make_pair(m, make_pair(n,p))`). If you use the latter, you'll want `make_tuple(m,n,p)`.

Comment: thanks for the answer,somehow it was working for multimap but fails in case of multiset, could you please suggest some possible reasons ?

Comment: @rishabh : `multimap` has a key and a value, `multiset` only has a key. What are you trying to accomplish? It's hard to help when you show nonsense code and don't explain the goal. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn thanks for the clarification,i am new to these concepts so I should better study them in greater detail before asking any further question...